# Check function overwriting in the derived class in CRTP pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

I'm trying to implement compile-time checking of correct implementation of  CRTP pattern.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

#define static_interface_check(BaseClass, DerivedClass, FuncName) \
    static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(&DerivedClass::FuncName), decltype(&BaseClass<DerivedClass>::FuncName)>::value, "CRTP error: function " #BaseClass "::" #FuncName " was not overwritten in the class " #DerivedClass); 

template <class T>
class Interface
{
public:
    Interface();

    void foo1()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->foo1();
    }

    void foo2()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->foo2();
    }
};

// Checking inside Interface<T> declaration results in incomplete type error, so I had to move it to the default constructor
template <class T>
Interface<T>::Interface()
{
    static_interface_check(Interface, T, foo1);
    static_interface_check(Interface, T, foo2);
}

class A: public Interface<A>
{
public:
    void foo1() { cout << "A::foo1()" << endl; }
};

template <class T>
void bar(Interface<T> &obj)
{
    obj.foo1();
    obj.foo2();
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    bar(a);

    return 0;
}
```

It fails during compilation as expected:

> error: static assertion failed: CRTP error: function Interface::foo2
>   was not overwritten in the class T

But I want to use also function overloading, const and non-const versions of the same function.

The question is: how can I implement it for the interface containing `void foo()`, `void foo(int)` and `void foo(int) const`?

Comment: You can take some inspiration from the NVI pattern, and have the methods to be overriden have different names than `Interface`'s methods (such as `doFoo1` and `doFoo2`).

Comment: This will work, but it has a disadvantage: these methods should be non-public and the base class will not be able to access them without typing `friend Interface<A>` in the beginning.